# What is the differential line displacement in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, physics

I'm trying to solve

> $\int\left [ -KR^{2} \right ]\hat{z}d\vec{l}\cdot \hat{a}$

around a circular loop which popped up in a physics working.

However, I am unable to do so.

To kick start the attempt, I understand that the integration limits involves only the polar angle $\phi$ over the interval from 0 to 2$\pi$.
The cylindrical radius s=R is held fixed as we integrate over the loop.
However, I am unable to break down d$\vec{l}$ into its constituent components in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: It is not necessarily very simple...$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\phi^2+dz^2$.  Maybe a little more background?

Comment: $d\vec{l}=rd\phi\hat{\phi}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the loop is a circle, say of radius $R$, we only care about the contribution in the direction of $\hat \phi$. Suppose we are at a point where the angle with the positive $x$-axis is $\phi$. We have that
$$
d\vec\ell = R\,d\phi\, \hat \phi.
$$
Geometrically, this approximates the small portion of arc length at the angle $\phi$, given generally as $R\Delta \phi\to R\,d\phi$ as an infinitesimal.

Comment: Just what I was looking to understand. Thanks, again.